# Trying to NPM start in a project I've been working on all day, but getting "errno: -4058, syscall: 'stat', path: 'C:\\Users\\All Users'"

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, react-scripts

Actually had this issue the day before yesterday and somehow it stopped. Today it started up again, and I don't really know what I did? Although it did happen right after I pushed my progress to Github. Now the script won't start in my local server. I'm just trying to create a Todo app. Please see below.

```
...\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\All Users'] {    
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\All Users'
```

There's no account named "All Users" on my computer. I saw some other questions with this kind of issue (and experimented with their suggestions to no avail), but none of them had this weirdly vague "All Users" path. Tried reinstalling npm, deleting node_modules, upgrading NPM @latest, messed with my Environment Variables paths in my system settings, and lastly, I even restarted the entire project once before, so I'd prefer to not do it again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try reverting your last git commit, does it go back to working?

Comment: It does work when I revert to previous commit, but it always happens sometime when I'm working on it. 20 minutes later, 2 hours later or later that night. Am I doing something to trigger this? It's really restricting my productivity. Also, there is react-scripts in my files.

Comment: I would carefully compare your two commits, maybe change a little bit at a time, see if anything triggers it.  If not...dunno, virus scanner?  You could spin up a linux vm... :)